# Issues with Extracting values from List in Managed Beans JSF2.0

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have been trying to display some values from the list in a input text box in JSF 2.0. The value is not getting displayed.Below is the code that im trying to run

```
<h:inputText id="targetDaysValueID" value="#{demandBean.filterSelectionVOList.targetDays}" required="false" style="height:22px;width:155px;float: right"></h:inputText>
```

Below is the error message that Im getting when I try to run the page containing the above code in a xhtml page.

```
ava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "targetDays"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:166)
at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:51)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:118)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
```

The code works fine in a datatable, I assign the list to the datatable & create a variable for the same and when I use the variable with the fieldname I want to display, the same works fine. But doesnt work when I try to display the value="#{demandBean.filterSelectionVOList.targetDays}"

Please Assist. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `#{demandBean.filterSelectionVOList}` resolves to a list. `h:inputtext` value CANNOT be a collection.

If `filterSelectionVOList` is not empty try for example:

`#{demandBean.filterSelectionVOList.get(0).targetDays}`

edited:

To display all data from the collection you can for example wrap your output component by `ui:repeat`:

```
<ui:repeat var="element" value="#{demandBean.filterSelectionVOList}">
    <h:inputText value="#{element.targetDays}" /> 
</ui:repeat>
```

also add a proper namespace definition:

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
```

You can also display elements using `h:dataTable` if this suits you better.

Comment: Thanks Michal for the response. I tried the above and it was throwing a parsing exception. Hence I tried this "#{demandBean.filterSelectionVOList[0].targetDays}". It worked. I was able to display the data. But the problem is, it always displays only the data in the 0th row. Can you please let me know how to extract all the elements from the list & not just the 0th element.